# Youtube Data Api V3.0 .NET samples issues

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, youtube-api

I'm trying to move from Youtube Data API V2 to V3 .NET. There are some samples [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet), but they are not up-to-date so I think that I need to convert those samples from PHP or Java Python.

If somebody is already converted those samples from PHP or Java Python to .NET, can you please provide me with the information?

Comment: Personally, I have no idea what you are asking. You have the .NET code samples, so what's missing?

Comment: .NET code samples are not working properly right now. I just got an answer from Jeff Posnick,Youtube Api Team. They are updating the samples for .NET and it will work properly.